# DidReceiveRemoteNotification is not fired in background mode in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin Forms and implemented Push Notification using Azure. Application fired  `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` method in foreground. But in background mode it is not called. I am storing Notification Received Count in this method and it's not increasing. I am using iOS verison 11.4 in my device. How can I solved this? I am calling below method in `DidReceivedRemoteNotification` method.

```
void ProcessNotification(NSDictionary options, bool fromFinishedLaunching)
    {            
        if (null != options && options.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
        {               
            NSDictionary aps = options.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;

            string alert = string.Empty;
            string type = string.Empty;

            if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("alert")))
                alert = (aps[new NSString("alert")] as NSString).ToString();
            if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("type")))
                type = (aps[new NSString("type")] as NSString).ToString();

            if (type.ToLower() == "menu")
            {
                SettingClass.MenuNotification = true;
                SettingClass.MenuNotificationCount += 1;
                MenuCount += 1;
                NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(MenuCount.ToString(), "MenuNotification");
            }
            if (type.ToLower() == "promo" || type.ToLower() == "promotion")
            {
                SettingClass.PromoNotification = true;
                SettingClass.PromoNotificationCount += 1;
                PromoCount += 1;
                NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(PromoCount.ToString(), "PromoNotification");                   
            }


            if (!fromFinishedLaunching)
            {
                //Manually show an alert
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(alert))
                {
                    MessagingCenter.Send("UpdateTabs", "NotificationCount");
                    UIAlertView avAlert = new UIAlertView(type, alert, null, "OK", null);
                    avAlert.Show();                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want handle remote notification in background you need update .plist file by adding next rows

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    ...some other permission...
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Or you can update it with `iOS Manifest Editor` like this
[image]

Comment: I have already provided permission and I am able to received notification in background mode. But the issue is method is not fired. So Notification count is not increasing.